# How to implement scrollToRowAtIndex:animated: method in WKInterfaceTable

Tags: watchkit, wkinterfacetable

in `WKInterfaceTable` class,there is a method called `scrollToRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)index`,it just scrolls the row at the specified index into view with scrolling animation.I know that there isn't a method called `scrollToRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)index animated:(BOOL)animated`,but I am wondering if there is a workaround to disable scrolling animation effect when scrolling the table.Thanks in advance. :-]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WatchKit 2.0 there is a method for TableView that do scroll to your desired row.

```
table.scrollToRowAtIndex(0)
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceTable_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceTable/scrollToRowAtIndex:

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to control the scrolling animation in the current version of WatchKit. Hopefully, we'll get something like this in a future update.